# C++ PPP Chapter 8 Exercise 1

Tags: c++

> 1. Modify the calculator program from Chapter 7 to make the input stream an explicit parameter (as shown in §8.5.8), rather than simply
>    using cin. Also give the Token_stream constructor (§7.8.2) an istream&
>    parameter so that when we figure out how to make our own istreams
>    (e.g., attached to files), we can use the calculator for those. Hint:
>    Don’t try to copy an istream.

I'd say this is the code that might relate to what I have to do here?

```
class Token_stream {
public:
    Token get();                // get a Token
    void putback(Token t);      // put a token back
    void ignore(char c);        // discard characters up to and including a c
private:
    bool full{ false };        // is there a Token in the buffer?
    Token buffer{ '0' };  
    // here is where putback() stores a Token
};


Token Token_stream::get()
{
    if (full) {             // do we already have a Token?
        full = false;       // remove Token from buffer
        return buffer;
    }

    char ch;
    cin.get(ch);            // look for any char including whitespace

    while (isspace(ch) && ch != '\n') cin.get(ch);

    switch (ch) {
    case '\n':
        return Token{ print };
    case print:
    case quit:
    case help:
    case '(':
    case ')':
    case '{':
    case '}':
    case '!':
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '*':
    case '/':
    case '%':
    case '=':
    case ',':
        return Token{ ch };    // let each character represent itself
    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
    {
        cin.putback(ch);    // put digit back into input stream
        double val;
        cin >> val;         // read floating-point number
        return Token{ number, val };
    }
    default:
        if (isalpha(ch)) {
            string s;
            s += ch;
            while (cin.get(ch) &&
                ((isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch) || ch == '_')))
                s += ch;
            cin.putback(ch);
            if (s == declkey) return Token{ let };    // declaration keyword
            else if (s == sqrtkey) return Token{ square_root };
            else if (s == expkey) return Token{ exponent };
            else if (s == sinkey) return Token{ c_sin };
            else if (s == coskey) return Token{ c_cos };
            else if (s == quitkey) return Token{ quit };
            else if (s == helpkey) return Token{ help };
            else return Token{ name, s };
        }
        error("Bad token");
    }
};
```

But I'm still not really sure what I have to do here? Like I just don't understand what I need to do and how.. Can anybody maybe help me out? I did some research on what istream is but I still am not really sure what to do here..

Comment: the task is rather explicit about what you should do. Did you read §8.5.8 and §7.8.2? What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Your code should no longer use `std::cin` but a `std::istream&` member instead.

Comment: But what exactly does that std::istream reference do?

Comment: Like idk it doesn't just magically connect to the input stream and replace cin right like idk I'm confused

Comment: Then, in your main, you should replace `Token_stream token_stream;` by `Token_stream token_stream(std::cin);` (and later replace `std::cin` by your own).

Comment: I looked at some solution online and in the private part of the token class this person wrote istream& is; I have no idea what this does and how its somehow connected to cin now?  istream is a class right so he just made a reference that doesn't even refer to anything? I'm just super confused now this is his code: https://github.com/Chrinkus/stroustrup-ppp/blob/master/chapter08/ex01_calculator.cpp

Comment: Do you understand [*reference*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)?

Answer (score 0):

He means to give **token** to function as an **argument** rather than using a `std::cin` statement inside a function.

```
void Token_stream::putback(Token t) //like this one
{
    if (full) error("putback() into full buffer");
    buffer = t;     
    full = true;    
}

// ignore Tokens up to specific kind
void Token_stream::ignore(char c) // and this one

{
    // first look in buffer:
    if (full && c==buffer.kind) {
        full = false;
        return;
    }
    full = false;

    
    char ch = 0;
    while (cin>>ch)
    if (ch==c) return;
}
```